# got same orientation angle for camera app

Tags: java, android, android-camera, screen-orientation

I am making camera app.In that my images are not saving in a right orientation.
I set

```
         <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

for activity in AndroidMainfest.
and now i am trying to get orientation it is giving 90 degrees always.
 I want to get mobile orientation with screenOrientation =portrait.
If I am using this code for get orientation:-

```
public int setPhotoOrientation(Activity activity, int cameraId) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

      int result;
    // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
    } else { // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed the call

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
```

after determining degrees and compensating for front facing camera.

But this only effects the way your camera preview is displayed on screen. Video recording or preview callbacks still deliver camera frames in their natural orientation.